# CMake: How to link two different versions of a library (32bit and 64bit) based on the system?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I've got two different versions of the same library, one should be linked for 32bit and one for 64bit systems. Currently, I manually modify the CMake file to change the linked library according the system on which I am making. Is it possible to make this an automated task? Can CMake itself decide which lib to use based on the system?

```
target_link_libraries(${PRODUCT}
                        #lib32
                        lib64)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use [`CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/variable/CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P.html)

```
if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
  set(MyLib lib64)
else()
  set(MyLib lib32)
endif()
target_link_libraries(${PRODUCT} ${MyLib})
```

Comment: Hey, would you please see if you can awsner this question of mine? http://stackoverflow.com/q/21852817/69537